# ASP.NET 301 redirect if contains last folder

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, web-config, http-status-code-301

I need to make a 301 redirect for all old links that contain (**/CID-VALUE**), e.g. `www.example.com/folder1/folder2/CID-1234`. These link could have been on any folder so I need something that catches all instances of CID- and the carried value and go to the replaced link with something like `?cid=VALUE` instead.

I'm working in ASP with VB.NET so use a web.config file.

Here's the code I currently use for 301 redirects

```
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^example(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/newexample/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your old URL structure is `/folder1/folder2/CID-1234` and I assume that folder1 and folder2 are examples and are variable.

```
<rule name="redirect-to-cid-page" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/([_0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/([_0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/new-cid-page.aspx?id={R:3}" statusCode="301" />
</rule>
```

So the rule above matches:

- **folder1** to `{R:1}` with the expresssion `([_0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)`
- **folder2** to `{R:2}` with the expresssion `([_0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)`
- **CID number** to `{R:3}` with the expresssion `([_0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)`

For **folder1**, **folder2** and the **CID number** I assume that they contain latin letters in any case and numbers.

Comment: I should have stated, the CID is just a tracking id so can be any value of around 6 to 10 characters/numbers. Also the issue I have is I need to cover anything from no sub folders to 3 or 4 sub folders with cid-value at the end. so is there a way to catch all that end with cid-value or do I have to specify and instance for 1 folder, 2 folder, 3 folder etc?

Comment: Yes, you will need to make multiple rules, one for each number of folders. I updated my answer to cover a more generic CID number.

Comment: Thanks I got this working once I added a rule for 0 folders, 1 folder, 2 folders etc